# Terminal not running C

Tags: c, macos, bash, terminal

so i'm trying to run a simple code for trial to see how i run a C code in terminal but getting this error:

```
main.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
main.c: line 3: `int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {'
```

any ideas why this is happening? runs fine on xcode?

The Code that i ran:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10;i++)
    {
        printf("IT WORKS!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

command to run file:

```
bash main.c
```

Comment: If the file name is `main.c~`, that's wrong. Please show the commands you typed to compile.

Comment: Command to compile: `cc -Wall main.c -o hello`. Command to run: `./hello`. Note that there's an option somewhere in Xcode to install the command line tools, e.g. the compiler. You need to do that first.

Comment: You need to run `xcode-select --install` to install the command-line tools before you can compile the way suggested above or by MByD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is returned from the shell that tries to parse your c file as a shell script, since you try to run your C code directly.

```
sh-3.2$ cat > mycode.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10;i++)
    {
        printf("IT WORKS!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
sh-3.2$ chmod +x mycode.c
sh-3.2$ ./mycode.c
./mycode.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./mycode.c: line 3: `int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {'
```

You can't run C code directly, first you need to compile it into an executable, and then execute the compiled executable.

for example:

```
$ gcc -o myexe main.c
$ ./myexe
```